# Referencing Row Number in R

Tags: r, row

How do I reference the row number of an observation? For example, if you have a `data.frame` called "data" and want to create a variable `data$rownumber` equal to each observation's row number, how would you do it without using a loop?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These are present by default as `rownames` when you create a `data.frame`.

```
R> df = data.frame('a' = rnorm(10), 'b' = runif(10), 'c' = letters[1:10])
R> df
            a          b c
1   0.3336944 0.39746731 a
2  -0.2334404 0.12242856 b
3   1.4886706 0.07984085 c
4  -1.4853724 0.83163342 d
5   0.7291344 0.10981827 e
6   0.1786753 0.47401690 f
7  -0.9173701 0.73992239 g
8   0.7805941 0.91925413 h
9   0.2469860 0.87979229 i
10  1.2810961 0.53289335 j
```

and you can access them via the `rownames` command.

```
R> rownames(df)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

if you need them as numbers, simply coerce to numeric by adding `as.numeric`, as in `as.numeric(rownames(df))`.

You don't need to add them, as if you know what you are looking for (say item `df$c == 'i'`, you can use the which command:

```
R> which(df$c =='i')
[1] 9
```

or if you don't know the column

```
R> which(df == 'i', arr.ind=T)
     row col
[1,]   9   3
```

you may access the element using `df[9, 'c']`, or `df$c[9]`.

If you wanted to add them you could use `df$rownumber <- as.numeric(rownames(df))`, though this may be less robust than `df$rownumber <- 1:nrow(df)` as there are cases when you might have assigned to `rownames` so they will no longer be the default index numbers (the which command will continue to return index numbers even if you do assign to `rownames`).

Answer (score 13):

Simply:

```
data$rownumber = 1:nrow(Data)
```

Comment: I can't think of a time when this would be useful though. Especially given the function `which`

Comment: It's useful if you need a sorting index.

Comment: I have a dataframe with two positional variables (say "Plot" and "Fruit_number") but at each position I have seven measurements. I want one of them, but I do not have a unique identifier. I can use filter and the mod function on row numbers to select a value. from each fruit within a plot. dplyr::filter(row_number() && 4 == 1)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps with dataframes, one of the easiest and most practical solutions is:

```
data = dplyr::mutate(data, rownum=row_number())
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the simplest way:

```
data$rownumber = 1:dim(data)[1]
```

It's probably worth noting that if you want to select a row by its row index, you can do this with simple bracket notation

```
data[3,]

vs.

data[data$rownumber==3,]
```

So I'm not really sure what this new column accomplishes.

Comment: You can use `nrow(data)` instead of `dim(data)[1]`.

Comment: rownames are characters not numeric. That might lead to confusion.