# Find row number from a row name in R

Tags: r, rows

How can I find the row number of a particular row name in R? I have found functions which allow you to find a row number for a particular matrix value, but not from a row name.

Comment: The answer is here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732728/referencing-row-number-in-r][1]

Answer (score 15):

You can use `which`

```
which(rownames(dat) == "theName")
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I did this, but this is what R returned: 
integer(0)  
It should be returning a row # somewhere in the 500s.  Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: @JoelleMarie the name is probably wrong, eg `which(c("a","b") == "c")` returns `integer(0)`

Comment: @user507 in my case the labels of my dataset happened to have a lot of spaces after the name, so i had to include those spaces as part of the label I wanted to find to get it working. By typing `row.names(dat)` you should see if this was also your case, provided this is still of interest for you.